# Jackson serialize/deserialize private builder

Tags: java, json, jackson, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to serialize/deserialize the [DynamoDB Record](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/dynamodb/model/Record.html) class using Jackson.

I have no control over this class, so I tried to use Jackson mixins.

I did the following:

```
@JsonDeserialize( builder = RecordBuilderMixIn.class )
private abstract static class RecordMixIn
{
}

@JsonPOJOBuilder( withPrefix = "" )
private abstract class RecordBuilderMixIn
{
}

var mapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .addMixIn( Record.Builder.class, RecordBuilderMixIn.class )
                .addMixIn( Record.class, RecordMixIn.class );
```

But I get the following error when I do `mapper.readValue(json, Record.class);`:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Builder class `com.surecloud.jackson.RecordObjectMapper$RecordBuilderMixIn` does not have build method (name: 'build')
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Would a @Builder annotation help?

Answer (score 0):

Add a constructor in RecordBuilderMixIn it is needed for the reflection that the object mapper uses to populate the object.

```
@JsonPOJOBuilder( withPrefix = "" )
private abstract class RecordBuilderMixIn {
    public RecordBuilderMixIn() {
        // constructor required by java reflection
    }
}
```

Also stop adding new line for the curybrackets after the method declaration it will just cause problems since no modern editors use this style.